# Spring MVC response header: why does setting header on param HttpServletResponse work when I return a new ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, httpresponse

I have this simple snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/consent-history", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
public ResponseEntity optionsHistory(HttpServletResponse response) {
    //response.setHeader("Allow", "GET,OPTIONS");
    //return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK); // this works too, strangely
    return ResponseEntity.status(200).header("Allow", "GET,OPTIONS").body(""); // this apparently works
}
```

I understand that returning a new ResponseEntity works, because I set header on it. But when I set header on the parameter `response`, it also works: I see header "Allow" set in my test. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you return an ResponseEntity. You already created a new response instead of your HttpServletResponse. So you set your header on that response but you return another one. That's why your header didn't work.

Comment: No, I meant that both work, not "not working". I create a new response and set headers, it works; when I set the header on the old, incoming response, and return a new ResponseEntity, it works, too.